# How to bind an IEnumerable collection to a Datagrid (items of variable contents)

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, datagrid, binding, ienumerable

While working with an excel file (.xlsx), the data I get from it is an IEnumerable(of Dictionary). When I bind this to my datagrid, I get the problem that I only see 2 columns. I've been tracing this problem and discovered that in the first row in the excel, there are only 2 values (cell C and D). I think the binding to datagrid looks at this first row to create its headers. This results in my datagrid only showing columns C and D.

The second row for example can contain info in column A, B, E and G, but as only columns C and D are shown, this row won't show data in the datagrid.

Is there a way to bind this variable length data to the datagrid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A DataGrid by definition displays a *regular grid* of information. As you surmised, if auto generate headers is on, it looks at the first record only as it should (what else could it do... with paged data etc?).

If you want to display it in a DataGrid the data needs to be uniform. That means that when you get your data from your dictionary you should probably populate a class that has A, B, C, D, E & G and just leave the unused entries blank.

*(If you define the columns and bindings in advance manually you might be able to bind the dictionary directly, but I have never tried sparce/irregular data on a DataGrid... give it a try).*

Comment: I've tried setting the columns manually in xaml in advance, but i only get the same 2 columns as well. Making a class for columns can't really be done either, as the number of columns varies.

Comment: Can you explain why "as the number of columns varies" is a problem with using a fixed shape class to hold the data? You can still vary the columns dynamically to match the desired output.

Comment: Let's say the columns until now go to "H". So i make a class which provides data storage for columns A-H. Then there's a file which has data until "V", because there is new functionality that needs to be implemented. This fixed data storage i was using will not store the data from G-V. Or am i missing something?

Comment: It really does sound like you need to pre-process the data, or at least parse it once to determine the layout and add columns dynamically. You could always make the entries an array property on your item and bind to indexed elements.